# Como corrigir imagem com "baixa qualidade" no Listview

Tags: vb.net

Galera eu estava usando o código abaixo para criar thumbnail de vídeo e mostrar em um ListView:

```
Dim cont As Integer = 0
    Dim thumbnail As New ImageList With {.ImageSize = New Size(200, 200)}
    Dim caminho_saida As String = "C:\..."
    Dim caminho_thumb As String
    Dim name_arquivos As String
    Dim xx As Image

    For Each zz In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(caminho_saida)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(zz)
    Next


    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Try
        For Each caminho_videos In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.mp4")
            name_arquivos = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(caminho_videos)
            caminho_thumb = caminho_saida + name_arquivos + ".png"

            Try
                Dim ffMpeg = New NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter()
                ffMpeg.GetVideoThumbnail(caminho_videos, caminho_thumb, 20)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(caminho_videos)
            End Try

            Using str As Stream = File.OpenRead(caminho_thumb)
                xx = Image.FromStream(str)
                thumbnail.Images.Add(xx)
            End Using

            ListView1.LargeImageList = thumbnail
            ListView1.Items.Add(name_arquivos, cont)


            cont += 1
        Next
    Finally
    End Try
```

O problema é que o resultado no ListView é uma imagem "ruim", sendo que a original tem a qualidade do arquivo original.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O que eu gostaria e de saber como eu concerto isso.

Comment: Não será o método `GetVideoThumbnail` que está a trazer uma imagem de fraca qualidade? Ou se abrir a imagem manualmente ela tem boa qualidade mas só quando coloca na `ListView` é que passa a ficar fraca?

Comment: Exatamente! Apenas quando coloco no listview que perde qualidade. Ex: Ná imagem acima à esquerda está o listview e olha como a última imagem da Paramount está ruim, já ná direita está a versão original da imagem que é jogada no listview (a imagem que sai do GetVideoThumbnail).

Comment: No PictureBox a imagem fica normal, mas no Listview não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente criar a imagem com a gestão de cores original:

```
Dim imagem As Image = Image.FromFile(strImagem, True)
```

Se mesmo assim não ficar como pretende, implemente o seguinte método:

```
Private Function RetornaImagemComQualidade(ByVal strImagem As String) As Image
    Dim imagem As Image = Image.FromFile(strImagem, True)
    Dim objBitmapImagem As Bitmap = New Bitmap(imagem.Width, imagem.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)

    objBitmapImagem.SetResolution(imagem.HorizontalResolution, imagem.VerticalResolution)

    Dim objGraphicsImagem As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBitmapImagem)

    objGraphicsImagem.Clear(SystemColors.Control)
    objGraphicsImagem.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    objGraphicsImagem.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear
    objGraphicsImagem.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality

    objGraphicsImagem.Dispose()

    Return objBitmapImagem
End Function
```

Passando o caminho da sua imagem por parâmetro.

### Edit

Só reparei agora que está a utilizar uma `ImageList` para guardar as imagens antes de as colocar na `ListView`. Experimente fazer o seguinte:

```
thumbnail.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
```

Outra solução passa por não fazer o *resize* das imagens na `ImageList` e mantê-las do mesmo tamanho, fazendo isso depois apenas na `ListView`.

Comment: Ambos não funcionam. O primeiro tem o mesmo resultado e o segundo retorna todas as imagens em um tom claro de cinza.

Comment: Com a primeira opção no PictureBox a imagem fica normal, mas no listview não.

Comment: Na segunda opção altere o "SystemColors.Control" para "Color.Transparent".

Comment: Imagens agora estão todas pretas.

Comment: Está difícil... e se retirar essa linha do Clear()?

Comment: quando mudei eu fiz esse teste também e continuou tudo preto. Eu fiz um redimensionamento da imagem para um tamanho (256, 256) e mostrei a mesma 
imagem no Listview e no Picturebox, mas a imagem ficou boa no picturebox e ruim no Listview. Não teria alguma ideia do que poderia ser?

Comment: Edição feita na resposta. O facto de estar a utilizar uma `ImageList` pode ser o problema.